# Is the FIFA 16 Ultimate Team database available anywhere?

Tags: data-request, web-crawling, games

I know there's already websites such as Futhead that can act as a database. However, I'm looking for something (preferrably a single file) that can actually be parsed, as I'm looking to make my own application using it. I suppose as a last resort I could simply crawl and scrape the Futhead website, but that would require a lot more effort to implement and would be significantly slower to run too.